# How to reject whitespace as input in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a code that would reject an answer that only contains whitespace/spaces.  So far I already made a code to reject empty inputs but once the user inputs spaces, the program accepts it.

How do I prevent this? Thank you!

```
    do {
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Dog's name: ");
            String dogName = null;
            dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            String n = dogName.replaceAll("\\s", "");

            if(dogName.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error: Name can't be empty.");
                continue;   
            }
```

Comment: `n` is your string with the spaces removed. You can just check `if (n.isEmpty())`.

Answer (score 4):

The method trim() would be quite handy in this case. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) :

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted.

You can use it this way:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Dog's name: ");
    String dogName = scan.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

    if (dogName.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Name can't be empty.");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will remove the leading and trainling white spaces only

Comment: Well if the String only contains whitespaces, then all of the whitespaces are both leading and trailing so the result is an empty String.

Comment: This will alter (trim) valid inputs too. In the case of dog names it's *probably* not going to matter, unless you have a dog called i.e. " Fido" with a leading or trailing space. If you use this code, you should be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help everyone! I just added .trim() to the code :)

So now it's:
String dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

Answer (score 0):

You may use String.matches to check for empty strings :

```
           if (dogName.matches("^\\s*$") || dogName.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error: Name can't be empty.");
                continue;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

dogName.trim() will remove leading and trailing white space, if the entire String is made of white space then this will replace all and leave an empty string. e.g.

"   dog    " -> "dog"

"  dog  name " -> "dog  name"

If checking for empty/blanks is going to be common then take a look at the StringUtils.isNotBlank for "inspiration" and write your own Static util methods based of those.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, update your code with

```
dogName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

so your code becomes, ...also remember to upadte your if statement.

```
do {
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Dog's name: ");
            String dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            String n = dogName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

            if(n.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error: Name can't be empty.");
                continue;   
            }
   }
```